# MySQL update request fails from Python

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to UPATE my forex table as and when I receive my exchange rates.
I run the following function

```
  def writeForexdb(Ticker, Rate):
    mycursor.execute(f"UPDATE `mydb`.`param_forex` SET `Rate` = '{Rate}' WHERE `mydb`.`param_forex`.`Ticker` LIKE '{Ticker}'")
    mydb.commit()
```

which works fine. But when I try the other method with the %s, it does not work.

```
def writeForexdbother(Ticker, Rate):
    mycursor.execute(f"UPDATE `mydb`.`param_forex` (Rate) VALUES (%s) WHERE `mydb`.`param_forex`.`Ticker` LIKE '{Ticker}'", 
                     (Rate))
    mydb.commit()
```

and I get the following error message:
Unknown column 'eurusd' in 'where clause'

I can't figure out my mistake...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wrong syntax there,

```
mycursor.execute("UPDATE `mydb`.`param_forex` SET `Rate` = %s WHERE `mydb`.`param_forex`.`Ticker` LIKE %s", (Rate, Ticker))
```